# BIGQUERY : Unsupported subquery with table in join predicate

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I try to run a query. there is a subquery on the join 'on' clause. Can i use subquery on the on clause. I got the error

Unsupported subquery with table in join predicate. Below is an example I made.

```
select '1' from `server.dataset.table` a 
join `server.dataset.table`  b 
on a.AccountNumber= (select max(m.AccountNumber) from `server.dataset.table`  m)
```

Comment: Are all the tables different? You name them exactly the same, but that would be an important fact to know :)

Answer (score 2):

I sugested that in the join you need to relate the priamary key from table A to table B.

here is the example code code.

```
select '1' from `server.dataset.table` a 
join `server.dataset.table`  b 
on a.primarykey=b.primarykey
where a.AccountNumber= (select max(m.AccountNumber) from `server.dataset.table`  m)
```

Comment: subquery is working but the subquery in join 'on' clause is not working.                 
  select '1' from `server.dataset.table` a 
join `server.dataset.table`  b 
on a.AccountNumber= (select max(m.AccountNumber) from `server.dataset.table`  m)

Comment: this query just get 1 row "select max(m.AccountNumber) from server.dataset.table m"?

Comment: Yes , it only gets 1 row